# add up positions from css in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, addition

I am trying to code a little game and therefore trying to move an object in a certain area. To get somewhat of a border I am trying to add up positions. However I will simplify this for you and this is what does not work: (in JS)

```
parseInt( $('#w'+w ).css( 'top' ) + $('#w'+w ).css( 'height' ) )
```

this should just add up the top position with the height of this element. When I print this out it will tell me it is 100. But when I print height and top without adding them up its height = 500 and top = 100 ( This is how it is in the css code ).
If i swap height and top and add this up the result is 500, so the first element. I got similar calculations, which fit. Any suggestions what went wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably concatenating strings:

```
// $('#w' + w).css('top') returns the string "100px"
// $('#w' + w).css('height') returns the string "500px"
parseInt("100px" + "500px") // 100
parseInt("500px" + "100px") // 500
```

I suggest that you change your code to this:

```
parseInt($('#w' + w).css('top')) + parseInt($('#w' + w).css('height'))
```

Comment: Thanks
parseInt( parseInt($('#w' + w).css('top')) + parseInt($('#w' + w).css('height'))) helps ut

Answer (score 0):

for top use position:

```
var position = $('#w'+w ).position();
console.log( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
```

for height or width use jQuery width() and height():

```
console.log( "width: " +$('#w'+w ).width() + ", height: " + $('#w'+w ).height() );
```

Comment: thank you. is there a 'function' for every css order?